# how to add key to object from array in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add a key value to javascript object,
i have an array like this :
`var a = [20, 21, 22];`

and i tried to convert it into a javascript object using this code : 
`var id = Object.assign({}, a);`

the result is : `{0 : 20, 1 : 21, 2 : 22}`

but, how to change the result like an object below ? :

`0 : {id : 20}, 1 : {id : 21}, 2 : {id : 22}`

any help will be appreciated

Comment: {id : 20, id: 21, id:22} is equivalent to just 1 of the id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment "the format of the object supposed to be like this: 0 : {id : 20}, 1 : {id : 21}, 2 : {id : 22}", this looks like a job for [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var input = [ 20, 21, 22 ];

var output = input.map( function( value ) {
    return { id: value };
});

console.log( output );
```

Or, in modern JavaScript using an arrow function:

```js
var input = [ 20, 21, 22 ];

var output = input.map( value => ({ id: value }) );

console.log( output );
```

Comment: Glad to help. Happy hacking! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can't and shouldn't have an object like `{id : 20, id: 21, id:22}`. Each key in the object should be unique, otherwise it beats the purpose of being a 'key'.

If you, hypothetically, had an object like

```
var a = {id : 20, id: 21, id:22};
```

,then how are you planning to access those elements? What will `a.id` return and how will it help you?

If you want to get `0 : {id : 20}, 1 : {id : 21}, 2 : {id : 22}`, you could do this this way:

```
let a = [20, 21, 22];
let obj = Array();
for(let i of a) {
  obj.push({id: i});
}
```

Comment: i'm so sorry, but the format of the object supposed to be like this: `0 : {id : 20}, 1 : {id : 21}, 2 : {id : 22}`

Answer (score 0):

`{id : 20, id: 21, id:22}` is equivalent to just 1 key/value pair. their is no way to have `{id : 20, id: 21, id:22}` as an object and keep values as 20, 21, 22

You can try making it into an array like

```
{id : [20, 21, 22]}
```

or

```
[{id:20}, {id:21}, {id:22}]
```

```js
var a = [20, 21, 22];
var result = [];

for(let i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    result.push({id: a[i]});
}

//console.log(result)
var id = Object.assign({}, result);
console.log(id);
```

Comment: have you ever heard about dustjs ? in dust, i can't render a standar array, it must be an associative array....

Comment: i tried your answer, but the console displaying : `id{ 0 : 20, 1 : 21, 2 : 22}`

Comment: you can create an array of objects which has objects [{id : 20}, {id : 21}, {id : 22}]

Comment: idk why, but using `push()` make my browser unresponsed... but thanks for trying to help me btw :)

Answer (score 0):

Create object like:
var collections = [], a = [20, 21, 22];

Iterate array a([20, 21, 22]), and add individual item in collections like below which is array.

```
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    collections.push({id: a[i]});
}
```

Cheers...