# Javascript - Add a new key to an object in an array

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me how can i achieve the following

```
activity = {}   // can have hotel , transport etc
day = [ {day: 'DAY01'} , {day: 'DAY2'}]
```

i want to add activity.hotel to day 01 object in day array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add key to object from array in javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45809754/how-to-add-key-to-object-from-array-in-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the precise day you want, for instance with `find`.

Then add a new key to the day object, by using the bracket notation, and assign your activity object.

```js
let activity = { hotel: 'TheHotel' }   // can have hotel , transport etc
let days = [ {day: 'DAY01'} , {day: 'DAY2'}]

// get the particular day to edit
let day = days.find(d => d.day === 'DAY01')
// attach the activity.hotel object you want. 
day['hotel'] = activity.hotel;

console.log(days)
```

or add directly the whole activity object, if you want :

```js
let activity = { hotel: 'TheHotel' }   // can have hotel , transport etc
let days = [ {day: 'DAY01'} , {day: 'DAY2'}]

// get the particular day to edit
let day = days.find(d => d.day === 'DAY01')
// attach the activity object you want. 
day['activity'] = activity;

console.log(days)
```

Comment: @mush I just edited my answer to show alternative, I read again the question and wanted to add only the "hotel" part.